# ORA-00936: missing expression Solution- Convert function

Tags: oracle, expression, where-clause, converters

when doing this query in oracle  I get the error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 - "missing expression"
```

If I run the query to the from of it gives me results, then I deduce that the problem comes from where, however, I cannot identify what it is

```
SELECT FECHADOC, FECHACONT, CLASEDOC, SOCIEDAD, MONEDA, TIPOCAMBIO, PERIODO, 
       REFERENCIA, TEXTOCAB, ID_REGISTRO 
FROM ESQUEMA.TABLE 
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(8),20211231,112) <= CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE()),112)
```

I already used:

```
 WHERE CONVERT( TO_CHAR(8),20201231,112) <= 
      (CONVERT(TO_CHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE()),112) )
```

and it keeps giving me an error

Comment: Are these static values, that you put in for the question? are you really comparing the static value of 20201231 to Today-90, or is there a table column here?

Comment: `convert` (with that parameter list), `dateadd` and `getdate` aren't built-in Oracle functions.  It appears that you are using functions from SQL Server or some other non-Oracle database.  I'm guessing that you haven't defined those functions locally hence the problem.

Comment: 20201231 and -90 are parameters that were resolved with that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really is Oracle, then `dateadd` and `getdate` aren't Oracle functions. Look like MS SQL Server ones. Also, `table` is reserved word for *tables*, you can't name a table (or any other object) *table*.

Anyway: looks like this is what you might be looking for:

```
SELECT FECHADOC, FECHACONT, CLASEDOC, SOCIEDAD, MONEDA, 
       TIPOCAMBIO, PERIODO, REFERENCIA, 
       TEXTOCAB, ID_REGISTRO 
FROM ESQUEMA.TABLE 
where to_date('20211231', 'yyyymmdd') <= trunc(sysdate) - 90;
```

Comment: esquema.table was only to exemplify that the name of the table was going, your answer helped me, thank you very much¡

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.